# Keras tokenizer: Keep Numbers as "words"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tokenize, text-processing

I am using the keras tokenizer for my text preparation.
Now I have x values like `26.07.2020` or `27.September 1993`.

I want to use the tokenizer either for adding `September` as a word to the index, but also 26, or 2020.

I used char_level=True before, but I think the model should perform better with having words like `September` as word token. Is this possible with the keras tokenizer and if yes, how?

Thanks alot.

Comment: by default, the tokenizer filters the punctuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `.` with whitespaces, the `Tokenizer` splits your sentence by whitespaces and then tokenize each word.

So a simple solution would be

```
x.replace('.', ' ')
```